# What do the open sets in the Urysohn Metrization Theorem look like?

Tags: general-topology

I am following Munkres' Topology and I am a bit confused about the Urysohn metrization theorem construction (Theorem 34.1). The proof goes as follows:

1. Show that there is a countable collection of continuous functions $f_n : X \to [0,1]$ having the property that given any point $x_0 \in X$ and any neighborhood $U$ of $x_o$, there exists an index $n$ such that $f_n$ is positive at $x_0$ and vanishes outside $U$. (This is done using Urysohn's lemma and a countable basis)
2. Taking the functions from step one the map $F: X \to \mathbb{R}^\omega $ is an imbedding ($\mathbb{R}^\omega $ is in the product topology), where $F(x)=\langle f_1(x), f_2(x),...\rangle$.

While I see that each step is correct, it seems to me that the function $F$ does not carry open sets to open sets. For example, if the set $X$ is to be $\mathbb{R}$ in it's usual topology, it's countable basis are $\epsilon$-balls less than $q\in \mathbb Q$ and $U=(0,1)$, then $F(U)$ must have an infinite number of sets different than $[0,1]$:

For there is an infinite number of base elements such that $U$ is strictly contained in them, like $(-1,2), (-2,3)$, etc; and to each of these open sets $W$ there is a function $f_i$ that maps $W$ to $1$ and vanishes outside of it. So there are infinite functions that map $U$ to $1$, and so $\pi_i (F(U))$ is $\{1\}$ for an infinite number of $i$'s and hence is not open ($\pi_i$ here is just the projection function onto the the $i$th cordinate)

There must be something wrong with this argument but I can't find what, what is it?

*Edit: Explaining my example better.

Take $X = \mathbb R$. Give it as a countable basis all the sets all the open sets with rational endpoints.

1. For each pair of pairs of rationals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that $(a,b)\subset (c,d)$ by Urysohn's lemma there is a function $g_{ab,cd}$ such that $g([a,b])=\{1\}$ and $g\left((-\infty, c] \cup [d, \infty)\right)=\{0\}$. Map each pair of pairs of rationals to a natural number, and applying that function to the indices of the $g_{ab,cd}$ gives us the required $f_n$.
2. Construct $F(x)=\langle f_1(x), f_2(x),...\rangle$.

My question is what $F((0,1))$ looks like here. It seems to me that there are infinite $f_i$ such that $f_i((0,1))=1$. For example, $g_{(0,1),(-1,2)}$ has this property. Because by point 1. $g_{(0,1),(-1,2)}$ is $1$ in the closed set $[0,1]$. Similarly $g_{(0,1),(-2,2)}$, and in general $g_{(0,1),(-i,i)}$ for $i \geq 2$. So it seems to me that $F((0,1))$ is not open.

Comment: $F[(0,1)]$ is **not** open in $\Bbb R^\omega$. It's "only" open in $f[X]$. This is essential to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid that I don’t understand your argument. (By the way, the function $f_n$ defined from some particular $B$ in a countable base is **not** necessarily $1$ at every point of $B$; in fact, this is possible only if $B$ is clopen.)

Suppose that $F(x)\in F[U]$ for some open $U$ in $X$. Then $x\in U$, and there is an $n_x$ such that $f_{n_x}(x)>0$ and $f_{n_x}[X\setminus U]=\{0\}$. Let $B_x=\{\langle y_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in\Bbb R^\omega:y_{n_x}>0\}$; this is a basic open set in $\Bbb R^\omega$, and $F(x)\in B_x\cap F[X]\subseteq F[U]$. It follows that

$$F[U]=\{F(x):x\in U\}\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in U}(B_x\cap F[X])\subseteq F[U]$$

and hence that

$$F[U]=F[X]\cap\bigcup_{x\in U}B_x\;,$$

which is open in $F[X]$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question boils down to why is $B_x$ an open set, couldn't it happen that an infinite number of coordinates are different from $\mathbb{R}$? That is what I tried to construct. I feel I am missing a really obvious piece.

Comment: @Shiranai: $B_x$ is an open set by the definition of the product topology in $\Bbb R^\omega$: it’s $\pi_{n_x}^{-1}[(0,\to)]$. What happens on other coordinates is irrelevant.

Comment: Lapsus brutus. My last question would be, how does $F(U)$ looks like in my example? It must be $[0,1]$ for an infinite number of coordinates and an open set a finite number of coordinates. Which coordinates are those finite ones?

Comment: @Shiranai: To be honest, I can’t make heads or tails of your example, apart from the fact that it embodies a misunderstanding about the Urysohn functions, as noted in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I added a better version, I hope it is more clear now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Shiranai: Why do you think that that’s a problem? It just shows that $F[(0,1)]$ is not a **basic** open set.

Comment: After spelling out the whole example, I think my confusion stemmed mostly from thinking that $F[X]$ was the whole $[0,1]^\omega$ (at least for my example). But it is not, $F[X]$ looks really weird in general including my simple example. Thanks for you guidance!

Comment: @Shiranai: You’re very welcome! (And yes, open sets in infinite products can indeed look really weird.)